# Combining multiple transforms in a RenderTransform

Tags: c#, wpf

Is it possible to influence a `RenderTransform` object with both a `ScaleTransform` and a `TranslateTransform`?

I would like to keep access to the `ScaleX` and `ScaleY` properties of a `ScaleTransform` while also performing a `TranslateTransform`, both on the same `RenderTransform`. For that reason I can't use the more generic `MatrixTransform`.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use a [`TransformGroup`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.transformgroup(v=vs.110).aspx) to composite the two transforms.

```
var finalTransform = new TransformGroup();
finalTransform.Children.Add(firstTransform);
finalTransform.Children.Add(secondTransform);
```